# UIImage from MASKED CALayer

Tags: uiimage, calayer, crop, mask, cgcontext

I'm in need of an UIImage from a Masked CALayer. This is the function I use:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

The problem is that the mask isn't maintained.
This is the completed code:

```
    CAShapeLayer * layerRight= [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layerRight.path = elasticoRight;
    im2.layer.mask = layerRight;

    CAShapeLayer * layerLeft= [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layerLeft.path = elasticoLeft;
    im3.layer.mask = layerLeft;

    [viewImage.layer addSublayer:im2.layer];
    [viewImage.layer addSublayer:im3.layer];


    UIImage *image_result = [self imageFromLayer:viewImage.layer];
```

If I visualize the viewImage, the result is correct, but if I try to obtain the image relative to the layer, the masks are lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [layer.renderInContext doesn't take layer.mask into account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896296/layer-renderincontext-doesnt-take-layer-mask-into-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved.
Now i obtaining the image mask and use CGContextClipToMask.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0);

{
   [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
   UIRectFill(rect);
   [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

   UIBezierPath *leftPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

   // Set the starting point of the shape.
   CGPoint p1 = [(NSValue *)[leftPoints objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
   [leftPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(p1.x, p1.y)];

   for (uint i=1; i<leftPoints.count; i++)
   {
       CGPoint p = [(NSValue *)[leftPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
       [leftPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)];
   }
   [leftPath closePath];
   [leftPath fill];
}

UIImage *mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);

{
   CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
   [im_senza drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
}

UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```