# CALayer mask inside rotatingHeaderView/rotatingFooterView doesn't work during auto-rotation animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, calayer, autorotate

It seems that if a CALayer, descendant of some UIViewController's `rotatingHeaderView` or `rotatingFooterView` has a mask, then the mask doesn't work during autorotation:

[image]

The code to create this shape:

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)].CGPath;

CALayer *l = [CALayer layer];
l.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
l.mask = mask;
l.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20);

[self.layer addSublayer:l];
```

Is there some way to fix or get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [layer.renderInContext doesn't take layer.mask into account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896296/layer-renderincontext-doesnt-take-layer-mask-into-account)